# Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated

Tags: java, mysql

My Code:

```
file ConnectionTest.java
package com.test.connection;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.junit.Test;



public class ConnectionTest {
@Test
public void getConnectTest5() throws Exception {
    //1、读取配置文件中的基本信息
    InputStream is = ConnectionTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");
    
    Properties pros = new Properties();
    pros.load(is);
    
    String user = pros.getProperty("user");
    String password = pros.getProperty("password");
    String url = pros.getProperty("url");
    String driverClass = pros.getProperty("driverClass");
    
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println(conn);
}
```

}

file jdbc.properties:

user=root
password=Aa123456
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false
driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Just remove the `Class.forName()` call. It is not needed anymore, and hasn't been needed by compliant drivers since Java 6, so hasn't been needed since **2007**.

Comment: When I remove Class.forName(),I still get the same error

Answer (score -1):

My Code Error:
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Comment: [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64001566/edit) to include the details and not post as answer.

Comment: Thank you, because the question is too long to display, A program error appears as an answer